# SQL query 'NOT IN' vs 'Join'

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, join, sql-in

NOT IN vs using a JOIN

```
SELECT  COUNT(*)
FROM TBL_A AS A
WHERE A.MailDatId = 185208
AND SUBSTRING(A.PIMBRecord,3,3) NOT IN (SELECT B.ServiceTypeId FROM TBL_B AS B WHERE B.IsStandard = 1);
```

---

```
 SELECT COUNT(*) FROM TBL_A AS A 
    LEFT JOIN (SELECT B.ServiceTypeId FROM TBL_B AS B WHERE B.IsStandard = 1) C
    ON SUBSTRING(A.PIMBRecord,3,3) = C.ServiceTypeId
    WHERE A.MailDatId = 185208
    and C.ServiceTypeId IS NULL
```

I have two queries as above, which one is more efficient?  Also how can I test the efficiency of queries in sql server?

Comment: Run both querieS together with the execution plan turned on

Comment: If there are null values in the ServiceTypeId column, the results will not be the same.

Comment: @jarlh if i update my second querys join to  'ON SUBSTRING(A.PIMBRecord,3,3) = COALESCE(C.ServiceTypeId, '')', will that fix it?

Comment: They are not equivalent. Null values will derail the first one. Try with and without null values and you'll see the difference right away.

Comment: Switch to NOT EXISTS, to avoid the null-issue.

Comment: Please ask 1 question per post. Please don't ask questions already asked. These are faqs. Before considering posting please read the manual & google any error message or many clear, concise & precise phrasings of your question/problem/goal, with & without your particular strings/names & site:stackoverflow.com & tags; read many answers. If you post a question, use one phrasing as title. Reflect your research. See [ask] & the voting arrow mouseover texts. Please clarify via edits, not comments. PS "efficient" doesn't mean anything in particular.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I would actually recommend `not exists` for this:

```
select count(*)
from tbl_a a
where
    a.mailDatId = 
    and not exists (
        select 1 
        from tbl_b as b 
        where b.isStandard = 1 and b.serviceTypeId = substring(a.PIMBRecord,3,3)
    )
```

Rationale:

- `NOT IN` is not null-safe, while `NOT EXISTS` is
- `JOIN`s usually better fit the use case when you want to return something from the other table - which is not the case here

For performance, you want an index on `tbl_b(serviceTypeId, isStandard)`

Comment: thank you for your answer. I have one question though... i compare your query with the first query i had (the one that uses NOT IN).. I compared the execution plan for both queries in sql server and the one you suggested only cost 8% and the other 92%.  However my question is... when I look at the Execution Times for both queries... Your query has higher CPU time and elapsed time.. when the other query is both cpu time and a lower elapsed time.. why is it so?  shouldn't the one with a lower cost take less time to execute?.. Thanks..